# continuous function from $D\setminus \{0\}$ to subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

[image]

a) is not true as $\mathbb{Z}$ is not dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

b) is not correct as inverse image of a closed set is going to be open set.

c) is not true as $f(D\setminus\{0\})$=is not a connected set.

Is my logics are correct against a,b,c? Please help.

Comment: I'd appreciate mentioning the source of this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To address the problems with your reasoning:

In the case of (a), you say that the function does not extend because $\mathbb Z$ is not dense. However, the density of the subset is only required for the extension to be *unique*. Think of it this way: the more points you specify, the harder it is to fit a function to them. If you specify on a dense set, you've so many values, you're left with no choice as to what happens elsewhere.

Note that specifying values on a dense set doesn't mean there is an extension, only that it is unique if it exists: the function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}0 &\mbox{if }x^2 < 2 \\ 1 &\mbox{if }x^2 > 2\end{cases}$$ is continuous on $\mathbb Q$ but has no continuous extension to $\mathbb R$. By contrast, given a function on a discrete set like $\mathbb Z$ (i.e. very much smaller than dense!) you can *always* extend because you've got space around every point in which you can do whatever you like. In fact, it is sufficient (though not necessary) that your set is closed: see the [Tietze extension theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem).

Your reasoning in (b) fails because, although you correctly identify that there is a closed set with an open pre-image, this is not in fact a problem because *closed sets can also be open* and vice versa. In particular, the whole space ($[0,1]$ or $D\setminus\{(0,0)\}$) is always both open and closed.

Your reasoning in (c) is correct.

Answer (score 4):

For (a), it seems to me that you could construct such a function easily, even though $\Bbb Z$ is not dense in $\Bbb R$ - linear interpolation would be one way to do this.

(b) is certainly true - just map $(x,y)$ to $x$.

I think you're right about (c).  It is certainly untrue, for the reason that you gave.

Comment: for the record: I did not downvote you. (as you can see from my profile, I do not downvote)

Comment: For (c), what about $(r,\theta)\to(1/(1-r),\theta)$?

Comment: @MattN. - I don't really care who downvoted me.  I'd be more interested in the REASON the unknown person downvoted me; if there's something wrong with my answer, I'd like to fix it.  Sadly, this was another hit-and-run.

Comment: @GerryMyerson - for (c), we're looking for a function whose values are in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: I withdraw my objection, and will look into getting a new pair of glasses.

Comment: @DavidWallace you are not sure about your answers?

Comment: I'm sure.  I'm just prone to understatement.

Answer (score 2):

(a) is true. If $x=n+\alpha$, where $0\le\alpha<1$, send $x$ to $\alpha f(n+1)+(1-\alpha)f(n)$.

(b) is true: map $\langle x,y\rangle\in D\setminus\{\langle 0,0\rangle\}$ to $x$.

(c) is false: $D\setminus\{\langle 0,0\rangle\}$ is connected, and $\{x\in\Bbb R:|x|>1\}$ is not.

Comment: @David: You’re right: I misread it.